# why this htaccess code uses 12 Entry Process?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, bots

```
SeEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^MJ12bot" not-allowed
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent (MJ12bot) not-allowed=1
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Mail.RU_Bot" not-allowed
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent (Mail.RU_Bot) not-allowed=1
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Mail.RU" not-allowed
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Qwantify" not-allowed
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^YandexBot" not-allowed
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^YandexMobileBot" not-allowed
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Seznambot" not-allowed
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Daum" not-allowed
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^DotBot" not-allowed
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Baidu" not-allowed
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^SemrushBot" not-allowed
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^BLEXBot" not-allowed
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent (Mail.RU_Bot) not-allowed=1
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent (Qwantify) not-allowed=1
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent (SeznamBot) not-allowed=1
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent (YandexBot) not-allowed=1
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent (YandexMobileBot) not-allowed=1
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent (Daum) not-allowed=1
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent (DotBot) not-allowed=1
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent (Baidu) not-allowed=1
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent (SemrushBot) not-allowed=1
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent (BLEXBot) not-allowed=1
```

I have set it in .htaccess file to block some bots it works but uses 12 Entry Process. why?
and which one is correct?

```
SeEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^example" not-allowed
```

Or

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent (example) not-allowed=1
```

Comment: https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setenvif

Comment: Thank yiu but what means ^ in this "^Bandit"  can I use it without ^ like this "Bandit"?

Comment: It's regex, for *start*

Comment: `SetEnvIfNoCase attribute regex [!]env-variable[=value]`

Comment: Can anyone explain why it uses exactly 12 static Entry Process? the bots are exactly 12 , in raw file I can see them blocked because it says 403 error for the bots , but the problem is the entry process is always 12/20 , it is weird because as I know that Entry Process is for php usage only not servers commands

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by *12 static entry process* and *12/20* or *for php usage only not servers commands* - All your showing is part of a .htaccess file. Ive linked to a site which explains it + given you the rule synopsis, not sure I can help much more.

Comment: I was created custom 403 error page called 403.shtml , blocked a lot of bots and a lot of ip addresses for some countries via .htaccess file , do you think it uses Entry Process because the server forward all to the custom 403.shtml error page ?